# How to Make Radio Button Into CSS Button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

How can I make the below radio buttons act and look like buttons?

### Ruby

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :action, placeholder: 'Enter a Custom Challenge' %>
  Or choose a featured challenge:
  <%= f.input :action, collection: ['Lose 10 Pounds', 'Exercise'], as: :radio_buttons %>
<% end %>
```

Right now I have it looking like a button, but I can't get it to work. For example, when I click on the box the background doesn't turn yellow and the radio[input] doesn't become checked.

In other words I want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/654/

To work like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/8/

### CSS

```
.challenge_action {
     list-style-type:none;
     margin:25px 0 0 0;
     padding:0;
}

.challenge_action span {
     float:left;
     margin:0 5px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}

.challenge_action label, .challenge_action input {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.challenge_action input[type="radio"] {
    opacity:0.011;
    z-index:100;
}

.challenge_action input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:yellow;
}


.challenge_action label {
     padding:5px;
     border:1px solid #CCC; 
     cursor:pointer;
    z-index:90;
}

.challenge_action label:hover {
     background:#DDD;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional challenge_action">
  <span class="radio">
    <label for="challenge_action_lose_10_pounds">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="Lose 10 Pounds" name="challenge[action]" id="challenge_action_lose_10_pounds" />Lose 10 Pounds
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="radio">
    <label for="challenge_action_exercise">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="Exercise" name="challenge[action]" id="challenge_action_exercise" />Exercise
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: just move the label down.. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/658/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `collection_radio_buttons` see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) for details

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :action, [['Lose 10 Pounds','Lose 10 Pounds'], ['Exercise','Exercise']], :first, :last
```

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com try the updated solution... I accidentally put `checkbox` code..

Comment: Thanks for the help Minato. Not looking for checkboxes though. `collection_radio_boxes` doesn't work. I just need to make `background:yellow` at this point when clicked.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com what's the  issue?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I guess I am in sleep

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com its almost 23:50 here... and I am feeling dizzy

Comment: Awesome that works, but now I have to see if the CSS I've been working on will work better with it

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com you didn't get buttons? or you haven't tried the css yet?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Glad it helped.. :D

Comment: Minato I can't get the CSS to work at all with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/660/. Maybe you wanna give it a stab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103328/discussion-between-minato-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the input outside of the label

http://jsfiddle.net/45kpk81e/

```
<input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="Lose 10 Pounds" name="challenge[action]" id="challenge_action_lose_10_pounds" />
<label for="challenge_action_lose_10_pounds">Lose 10 Pounds</label>
```

Comment: Khelmo the HTML is generated via the ruby. How can I adjust the ruby so that it will refect the HTML you are suggesting?

Comment: I don't think I can so I need to change the CSS to reflect the HTML, not the other way around I think